# How to solve Sanity warning: You have configured Sanity client to use a token in the browser

Tags: reactjs, token, sanity

I'm using ReactJS for the front-end and Sanity for the back-end.

I came across this warning and I have read [this linked documentation](https://www.sanity.io/help/js-client-browser-token) but I'm not sure how to apply in this case. I'm sure that I don't want to ignore the warning if it's for security issue.

[image: Sanity warning]

- I put my secret Sanity token inside an `.env` file, I thought this would work but apparently they say it would be exposed in the app bundle.
- There are 2 suggestions in [this document](https://www.sanity.io/docs/keeping-your-data-safe#e2a77f7391df) but it doesn't say how to apply it.

-> So what would be the right way to configure the token in this case? And can you help me understand how to apply it, please? Thanks everyone!

---

**client.js**

```
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client'

export const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2022-02-01',
  useCdn: true,
  token: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN,
})
```

Comment: there are 2 links under Datasets visibility. Have you read them already?

Answer (score 1):

According to the instructions of this [document](https://www.sanity.io/help/js-client-browser-token), you just need to add the "ignoreBrowserTokenWarning: true" code inside the object passed to sanityClient() like below and the warning will never appear again!

```
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client'

export const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2022-02-01',
  useCdn: true,
  token: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN,
  ignoreBrowserTokenWarning: true,
})
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Khoa. But what if I really want to hide my token and not ignore the security warning? Is there another way to consider about this?

Comment: @JuJu As long as your token is in the environment variable it should be fine. Also, this is Sanity saying it should be fine https://www.sanity.io/help/js-client-browser-token